# How to skip some XSLT elements if some XML element does not exist in the definition?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
<element>
 <A>192.168.188.100</A>
 <B>/shelf=1</B>
 <C></C>
</element>
<element>
 <A>192.168.188.100</A>
 <B>/slot=1</B>
</element>
<element>
 <A>192.168.188.23</A>
 <B>/port=client:1:3:1-2</B>
</element>
</data>
```

I have XSLT mapping which works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/"> 
    <max:SyncCIDW>
    <max:CIDWSet>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="data/element" />
    </max:CIDWSet>
    </max:SyncCIDW>
</xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="element"> 
    <max:CI>
        <max:CINUM><xsl:value-of select="A"/></max:CINUM>
    </max:CI>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But now I want to process only those elements which have element `C` in the definition. So `C` element may have value or not but only ELEMENT which has `C` should be processed?

So basically my output for this example should have only 1 element in result.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `<xsl:apply-templates select="data/element" />` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="data/element[C]" />`.

Comment: Hi Martin, sorry if I may have one more question - what if except of C element I should have also and some D element in order to process that XML?so it means multiple conditions must be fulfilled to have both C and D?

Comment: is it maybe in that case like this - data/element[C][D] or what is the correct syntax?

Comment: `data/element[C][D]` checks that `element` has both (at least one) `C` and `D` element. You can also write `data/element[C and D]` if you like.